# How to temporarily increase the z-index of a div onclick of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to mimic the behavior of a taskbar, when clicking on an icon (button), it should raise the z-index of a div, so as to give focus to that div in case there's another div covering it. It should not be spammable, one raise to give focus should be enough.

However it should also reduce its z-index added if another button is clicked so as not to raise it too much every time it's clicked.

I would prefer if the way to target the buttons are not using the `id` as it will not be reusable, since the tool have many ways to trigger one div.

Please see the code so far:

```css
.a-bg {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.b-bg {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.c-bg {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a-bg" id="a-bg">A</div>
<div class="b-bg" id="b-bg">B</div>
<div class="c-bg" id="c-bg">C</div>

<div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 100px;">
  <button class="a-btn">A</button>
  <button class="b-btn">B</button>
  <button class="c-btn">C</button>
</div>

<p>Another set of anchor links that does the same function as the buttons above.</p>

<div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 100px;">
  <a class="a-btn" href="#">A</a>
  <a class="b-btn" href="#">B</a>
  <a class="c-btn" href="#">C</a>
</div>
```

There's no JS yet, but in this sample, what I hope to achieve is, if a user clicks `A`, it will raise its z-index and overlap B and C... same goes for the other buttons.

A user should be able to click each button repeatedly to switch between the different divs.

I'm a newbie in JS and it's why I cannot complete it on my own.

```js
let aBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("a-btn");
let bBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("b-btn");
let cBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("c-btn");

if (aBtn.isClicked) {
  document.getElementById(a-bg).style.zIndex = 1;
}

if (bBtn.isClicked) {
  document.getElementById(b-bg).style.zIndex = 1;
}

if (bBtn.isClicked) {
  document.getElementById(c-bg).style.zIndex = 1;
}
```

I know this script is full of errors, but I'm thinking of it being done somehow like this.

That's all for now... thank you in advance to any help or pointers on how I can achieve this.

Comment: Reading up about addEventListener should help. You could have a class called 'clicked' which has a high z-index.  Set a function to be run when a button is clicked. Go through all the buttons removing clicked from their classList then add clicked to the classList of the clicked button. Have a go and if you get stuck put your new JS into your question so we can help.

Comment: Thank you kindly, will now test this and the first answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an event listener and add a data attribute to it, ie the id of the div. Then use this to toggle the z-index.

Something like this should work, it toggles the clicked box z-index to 1 and should change the others to z-index -1. Its something for you to play around with but gives you the idea how the event handler works.

CSS

```
.a-bg {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index:-1;
}

.b-bg {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index:0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index:-1;
}

.c-bg {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index:-1;
}

.show{
z-index:1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="a-bg" id="a-bg">A</div>
<div class="b-bg" id="b-bg">B</div>
<div class="c-bg" id="c-bg">C</div>

<div id="button" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 100px;">
  <button class="a-btn" data-box="a-bg">A</button>
  <button class="b-btn" data-box="b-bg">B</button>
  <button class="c-btn" data-box="c-bg">C</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#button button').click(function() { 
var box = $(this).attr('data-box');
$('#' + box).addClass('show').siblings().removeClass('show');
 alert(box); // Alerts the box id selected
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I will test this and see if I can make it work. This answer seems good, although I will have to make adjustments and not use `id` cause it will make my other buttons that trigger the same div unable to use this function.

Comment: Try things like $('#box').toggleClass('show').siblings().toggleClass('hide'); Just play with it, You have the id of the box to do whatever you want with, also good to learn what siblings do etc. Also it needs to use the id to select the box but you could use the class name as long as it matches the data-box info. You just change the $('#box') to $('.box').

Comment: and sorry i changed $('#' + box).addClass('show').siblings().removeClass('show'); The $('#' bit needed to add the box id. My bad

Comment: Thank you again, it worked as needed, but I will have to test it more if it will really work. But this is a really great help for starters. Thank you kindly ^_^